# Can I open 2nd emulator concurrently in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I have an emulator running, I want to run one more emulator to run simultaneously to check if multiple phones can upload data on the database simultaneously. So is it possible to open multiple emulator instances in android studio

---

I have tried this :
1) Open AVD Manager
2)Create a new Device
3)In the run menu click edit configurations
4)add a configuration by clicking + button
5)Rename your new configuration and add module as app
6) click apply and ok
7)Select the renamed configuration in the toolbar and select the new device and start running the application A new emulator will open

Comment: Why the hate on this question?  I have the same question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have emulators created, after that just run and build the app on the desired device. its okay.

Comment: Glad to help you.